# Gridview - Binding a collection within a Collection

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

```
Class Section
    List<Group> groupList

Class Group
   List<Products> productList
   Group ID
   Group Name

Class Product
   Product ID
   Product Name
   Product Details
```

Using C#, .NET 4.0, How do I bind this data to the GridView so that I have this format

```
G1_Name
       P1_Name   P1_Details
       P2_Name   P2_Details
G2_Name
       P3_Name   P3_Details
       P4_Name   P4_Details
```

Thanks

Comment: What language are you referring to?

Comment: Could you please indicate the language you're using?

Comment: Sorry, C#, and I am using .NET 4.0

Comment: Also, is this an ASP .Net question? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: This would be a ASP.NET question

Answer (score 1):

One solution (of many possible):

- A GridView that is data bound to a list of Groups
- with a TemplateField that contains a data-bound list control (e.g.`Repeater`, `DataList`, or evan another `GridView`).
- where the data-bound list control's DataSource property is bound to the Group.ProductList property:

.

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ...>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ... DataSource='<%# Eval("ProductList")) %>'>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         ... controls bound to Product properties
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:Repeater>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Well, In the example, I get a server tag not well formed error.

Comment: @JamshaidKamran - the example has ellipses that you need to replace with your own code, so as it stands, it is not well formed.

Comment: that is a basic thing, But I managed to resolve it by parsing the object returning from eval to its binding item class. That was the error, plus there is an extra bracket at the end of your `eval()` call.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to bind a hierarchical collection.  From what you describe, I would recommend using a ListView instead of a GridView.  You'll get a lot more control and flexibility over the display of your data.  However, the choice is yours and the code below can be easily modified for use in a GridView.

The code will produce the following structure:

[image]

**ASPX**

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listView">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <ul><asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></ul>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><%# Eval("GroupName") %>
                <asp:ListView runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("productList")%>'>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <ul><asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder></ul>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li><%# Eval("ProductName") %> - Details: <%# Eval("ProductDetails") %></li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

**C#**

```
        public class Section
        {
            public List<Group> groupList { get; set; }
        }

        public class Group
        {
            public List<Product> productList { get; set; }
            public int GroupID { get; set; }
            public string GroupName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Product
        {
            public int ProductID { get; set; }
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public string ProductDetails { get; set; }
        }

        Section section = new Section { groupList = new List<Group>() };

        Group group = new Group { GroupID = 1, GroupName = "Fruits", productList = new List<Product>() };
        Product product = new Product { ProductID = 1, ProductName = "Apples", ProductDetails = "On Sale" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 2, ProductName = "Oranges", ProductDetails = "Not on Sale" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 3, ProductName = "Pears", ProductDetails = "Big Spender Sale" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 4, ProductName = "Grapes", ProductDetails = "Not on Sale" };
        group.productList.Add(product);

        section.groupList.Add(group);

        group = new Group { GroupID = 2, GroupName = "Vegetables", productList = new List<Product>() };
        product = new Product { ProductID = 5, ProductName = "Carrots", ProductDetails = "Not on Sale" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 6, ProductName = "Celery", ProductDetails = "Last week only" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 7, ProductName = "Eggplant", ProductDetails = "Big Spender Sale" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 8, ProductName = "Oniones", ProductDetails = "N/A" };
        group.productList.Add(product);

        section.groupList.Add(group);

        group = new Group { GroupID = 3, GroupName = "Meat", productList = new List<Product>() };
        product = new Product { ProductID = 9, ProductName = "Beef", ProductDetails = "On Sale" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 10, ProductName = "Pork", ProductDetails = "Back for two weeks" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 11, ProductName = "Chicken", ProductDetails = "On sale" };
        group.productList.Add(product);
        product = new Product { ProductID = 12, ProductName = "Turkey", ProductDetails = "Going fast" };
        group.productList.Add(product);

        section.groupList.Add(group);

        listView.DataSource = section.groupList;
        listView.DataBind();
    }
```